# Is it possible to call past date UILocal Notification?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uilocalnotification

I have to added a local notification for next 30 days(June-01-2013 t0 June-30-2013).

For Example:

I have to change the date on the "settings" to June-15-2013, and then I have to change the date to June-05-2013. The local notification not called for the (June-01 to June-15). After June-16 is working fine.

My question is

1) Any restrictions for the UILocalNotification to fire the past dates?

2) Is it possible to fire the local notification for past dates?

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this is one of the situation i had faced when cam testing of robustness of the app. My app was also issuing notification for future dates. All goes well, if user does not change the date. But as part of testing, changing date to future and then past makes disables some notification which were suppose to appear.

The way i workaround this situation was responding to following call back in **application Delegate**

```
-(void)applicationSignificantTimeChange:(UIApplication *)application
```

Here i re-issued all the notifications as per required from the current date. That did the trick in my case. It's a heavy solution as all notifications has to be deleted and re-issued, but did the required for me.

There is one more case where you may required to **re-Sync** the notification. User may had also changed the date, when app is closed. For this, i made the application to reSync the notification everytime it launches. You can optimize this approach, by checking if there is significant change in date or not.

Answer (score 3):

Apple docs states that

> If the specified value is nil or is a date in the past, the
>   notification is delivered immediately.

So if you are setting the fireDate of a local notification in the past the notification  will be fired immediately.

Also your case I think is a special one because you are manually change the device date settings. The date settings may be changed when the time zone is changed but your case is different, you are not changing the time zone, you just change the date and I think the local notifications before (in the past) your new date are ignored.